# React redux tollkit with saga - dispatch multiple action

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, redux-saga

Hi I'm new using React with redux toolkit + redux saga.
My scenario is to show updated list after CRUD operation.
Currently data is saved successfully, and updated list is showing after refreshing the page.

If I'm calling multiple dispatch() then also it's not working.
Like this:

```
if (flag === "add") {
  handleAddEditModalClose();
  const body = { appname, package: packagename, version };
  await dispatch(saveVersionsData_init(body));
  await dispatch(getVersionsData_init());
}
```

**Component Page:**

```
const versionsdata = useSelector((state) => state.versionsdata.data);
const isLoading = useSelector((state) => state.versionsdata.isLoading);
const status = useSelector((state) => state.versionsdata.status);
...

useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(getVersionsData_init());
  setData(versionsdata);
}, [dispatch]);

const handleSubmit = async () => {
  if (flag === "add") {
    const body = { appname, package: packagename, version };
    await dispatch(saveVersionsData_init(body));
    handleAddEditModalClose();
  }
...
}
```

**Slice:**

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  data: [],
  isLoading: false,
  status: "error", 
};

export const versionsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "versionsSlice",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    getVersionsData_init(state, action) {
      state.isLoading = true;
      state.status = "initializing";
    },
    getVersionsData_sucess(state, action) {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.status = "success";
      state.data = action.payload;
    },

 
    saveVersionsData_init(state, action) {
      state.isLoading = true;
      state.status = "initializing";
    },
    saveVersionsData_sucess(state, action) {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.status = action.payload.status;
      //state.data = action.payload;
    },
    ....
  },
});

export const { getVersionsData_init, getVersionsData_sucess, saveVersionsData_init, 
saveVersionsData_sucess, updateVersionsData_init, updateVersionsData_sucess, 
deleteVersionsData_init, deleteVersionsData_sucess } = versionsSlice.actions;
export default versionsSlice.reducer;
```

**Saga:**

```
import { all, take, takeEvery, put, fork, call } from "redux-saga/effects";
import * as slice from "../slices/VersionsSlice";
import * as api from "../api/VersionsApi";

export function* getVersionData_init_api({ payload }) {
  try {
    const res = yield call(api.getallappversion, payload);
    if (res.status === 200) {
      yield put(slice.getVersionsData_sucess(res.data));
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("get version data error");
  }
}
export function* getVersionData_init_saga() {
  yield takeEvery(slice.getVersionsData_init, getVersionData_init_api);
}

export function* saveVersionData_init_api({ payload }) {
  try {
    const res = yield call(api.createnewappversion, payload);
    if (res.status === 200) {
      yield put(slice.saveVersionsData_sucess(res.data));
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("save version data error");
  }
}
export function* saveVersionData_init_saga() {
  yield takeEvery(slice.saveVersionsData_init, saveVersionData_init_api);
}
export const versionsSaga = [fork(getVersionData_init_saga), 
fork(saveVersionData_init_saga), fork(updateVersionData_init_saga), 
fork(deleteVersionData_init_saga)];
```

Please anyone help me sort this out

Comment: You can't use `await` with normal redux actions (unless you use some special middleware). I would move the request for new data into the sagas.

Comment: Do you have a good reason to use sagas? Nowadays we mostly discourage that unless you use very advanced saga features you cannot get any other way. Data fetching is not an advanced use case in that light. See https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2022/05/presentations-evolution-redux-async-logic/

Comment: @Martin Kadlec, thanks for reply I tested without using `async await` same thing happened

Comment: @phry thanks for reply, as per our project requirements we need to use saga. The link you provide is very informative

Comment: @mitu1234 I can only recommend talking to whoever is giving you those requirements - it's neither good time spent on learning nor a good idea for most real projects nowadays. That's why we as the Redux team mostly discourage its use (unless you really use things like action channels). It ends up being a lot more code, doesn't work nicely with TypeScript, and is a big learning hurdle for everyone onboarding.

Comment: If you must use saga, then you probably want to `put` the `getVersionsData_init` action inside of the `saveVersionData_init_api` saga handler.  But I hate saga too.

Comment: phry your suggestions sounds good. I would really apply these in future. However in this project I used things as @Linda Paiste suggested and it worked. Can you suggest what would be convenient to use as middleware in place of saga with reduxtoolkit

Comment: @mitu1234 redux-toolkit comes with [thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) middleware built in.  It also includes the [createAsyncThunk](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk) helper to manage dispatching pending/fulfilled/error actions.  You can also use [RTK Query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview) which uses thunks and createAsyncThunk internally.

Comment: You don't need to migrate your entire app at once, you could keep saga in some places and use thunk in others.